# Javascript functions - if (scriptTag.src.match

Tags: javascript, jquery, shortcode

I have this code this is for YouTube Video.

```
if (scriptTag.src.match(/(youtube|youtu|)\.(com|be)\/((watch\?v=([-\w]+))|(projects\/([-\w]+)\/([-\w]+))|([-\w]+))/)) {
```

that what I want to change is example:

```
scriptTag.src.match any url
```

so i want to do function with any url or with short code example: `scriptTag.src.match [my wp shortcode]`

I hope that you understand what i try to do, and i hope i get help thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? Code that matches any valid youtube video url? And what is the structure of `scriptTag.src`, please provide specific example of input and desired output.

Comment: here is full code this is a WordPress Plugin [link](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/video-overlay-ads/trunk/js/ ) Thanks for your help

Comment: That code doesn't include the code that you have posted here and doesn't explain what you mean by `any url`. What do you want to match, what type of url?

Comment: I'm trying to modify that plugin, so thats shows banner ads in YouTube and Vimeo Video, that what i want to do is to show ads in any video bot just from YouTube and Vimeo, once again thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check whether given url is associated with YouTube or Vimeo then you can simply use `startsWith` method of string.

Assume that `url1`, `url2` and `url3` are equivalent to `scriptTag.src`, which they are considering the code that you have linked. In that case, you can simply write a validation function like this.

```
function checkUrl(url) {
  if (url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com') ||
      url.startsWith('https://vimeo.com')) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

here is a snippet that shows usage of that function.

```js
const url1 = 'https://www.youtube.com/whatever';
const url2 = 'https://vimeo.com/whatever';
const url3 = 'http://wrongSource.com'

function checkUrl(url) {
  if (url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com') ||
      url.startsWith('https://vimeo.com')) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

if (checkUrl(url1)) {
  console.log('url1 is valid');
  // do some stuff
} else {
  console.log('url1 is not valid');
  // do nothing
}

if (checkUrl(url2)) {
  console.log('url2 is valid');
  // do some stuff
} else {
  console.log('url2 is not valid');
  // do nothing
}

if (checkUrl(url3)) {
  console.log('url3 is valid');
  // do some stuff
} else {
  console.log('url3 is not valid');
  // do nothing
}
```